How to fetch documents based on user groups in mysql?
I am having 5 tables users,,groups user_groups, documents and document_groups table. I want to fetch all documents that belongs to users with their groups
Users Table



id
name
email




1
John
john@yopmail.com


2
Martin
martin@yopmail.com


3
Kane
kane@yopmail.com



Groups Table



id
group_name




1
Accounts Group


2
IT Group



User Groups Table



user_id
group_id




1
1


2
1


3
2



John and martin belongs to Accounts Group and Kane belongs to IT GROUP
Documents Table



id
document_name
share_type




1
Policy Document
all


2
Personal Document
group



Now Fisrt document will be visible to all users in database but 2nd document should be accessible to some groups may be 1 or more then 1.
Now we have last table
Document Groups



id
group_id
document_id




1
1
2



Now 2nd document should only accessible to Account Groups(Group id :1) and in Account Groups only have 2 users John and Martin
I have tried below code
SELECT *
from documents 
lEFT Join document_groups
  on document_groups.document_id = documents.id 
JOIN user_groups
  on document_groups.group_id = user_groups.group_id 
where documents.share_type = "all" or user_groups.user_id = 1

So my final outupt if i logged in as User John



document_id
document_name




1
Policy Document


2
Personal Document



So my final outupt if i logged in as User Kane



document_id
document_name




1
Policy Document




Please do note that document_groups.group_id CAN have the value null() because of the LEFT JOIN to document_groups.  Ask yourself what will happen to JOIN user_groups on document_groups.group_id.... when this happens....

Looks like you need an EXISTS, to check whether there exists a matching document_groups and user_groups pair for that document and user.
select d.*
from documents d
where (
  d.share_type = 'all'
  or exists (select 1
    from document_groups dg
    join user_groups ug on dg.group_id = ug.group_id 
    where ug.user_id = @user_id
      and dg.document_id = d.id 
  )
);


I'd prefer not OR in WHERE but UNION ALL... the query will be more fast and simple.

@Akina can you post as answer?

@Akina Depends on how good the optimizer is. Not sure about MySQL but in SQL Server this is transformed into a left-semi-join with a pass through filter, so it's pretty efficient.

Not sure about MySQL And you're doing it right.
